# chart.js how to configure the lable for both axis

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

[image]

I want to create the x and y axis like image above. Can you please tell me how to do this in Chart.js

For x axis i have done like this

```html
                        xAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'YEAR',
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                min: 1,
                                max: 30,
                                autoSkip: false,
                                callback(value) {
                                    debugger; // eslint-disable-line
                                    return value % 2 == 0 ? value : null; // eslint-disable-line
                                },
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                            },
                        }],
```

Comment: what you have already tried?? Please share the codes

Comment: @tuhin47 I have added code for x axis. but donno how to do for y axis

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, it's almost the same as for the x axis so you will get:

```
xAxes: [{
     scaleLabel: {
         display: true,
         labelString: 'YEAR',
      }
 }],
 yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
         display: true,
         labelString: 'Y label',
       }
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple yAxes. You need to add this.

```js
yAxes: [{
  scaleLabel: {
    display: true,
    labelString: 'Label String',
  },
  {
    ticks: {
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      autoSkip: true,
      maxTicksLimit: 250,
      callback: function(value) {
        return value % 250 === 0 ? value + 'k' : null;
      }

    }
  }
}]
```

Moreover if you need `1000k` as `1m` you can write a function for that and use the function inside callback